# WAL configuration SSL Off

Tags: postgresql, docker, replication, wal

I am trying to configure a docker-compose to create a master and slave servers local using WAL to replicate databases, and it is not working, because of some problems in the configuration.

I am receiving this error in the image below:

[image]

All my code is here:

https://github.com/Oracy/postgres

To run is just `docker-compose up -d`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no matching `pg_hba.conf` entry for the incoming connection at the database server. Look at the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: 'There is no matching pg_hba.conf' there is, here: `host replication replicator slave  md5` last line of file. and there is no postgres log on `/var/log/postgresql/`

Comment: Please don't post text as images.  Your error message mentions an IP address and a host name.  Neither of them match your pg_hba.conf entry

Comment: The log file typically is in the directory specified by the `log_directory` configuration parameter. If there is no matching `pg_hba.conf` entry, then you have found the problem.